# Flutter http.post Future gives different Errors on different emulators or gives back nothing

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, http, xmlhttprequest, emulation

I have this Future and it works as a normal login form,
it workt perfectly some time ago but now it has some problems.

When i start it on chrome it only works when i use this extra cors part at the URL, because if i dont write it in i get this: Error: XMLHttpRequest error..
When i start it on an pixel emulator it gives nothing back.
And when i start it on an real samsung device it only works when i cut out the cors part of the URL if not it gives me this error: Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with

And the php script works fine

Does somebody has an answer to this problem?

```
Future<String> senddata() async {
print(passwort.text);
print(eMail.text);


final response =
await http.post("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.nothinghere.de/2/StillNothing.php", body: {
  "eMail": eMail.text,
  "passwort": passwort.text,
});

print(response.body);

var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
var key = datauser["key"];
var id = datauser["id"];

var lol = response.body;

if(key==69){
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('token', key);
  prefs.setString('id', id);

  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Schueler()),
  );
}
return lol;
}
```

Comment: have you tested the API endpoint is working, better confirm by requesting a post-call using postman

Comment: Yeah the backend php script works perfectly